# OPTIONS preflight request getting 400 bad request on https

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wcf

I have Ajax call on front end and i am calling WCF service through ajax call but ajax call has some adding headers that's why first preflight OPTIONS request is raise and its falling because of "url" has been blocked by cors policy.

I have added Below Code on my web.config file but still it's working.

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="DELETE" allowed="false" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, cache-control, content-type, authorization, context" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>


$.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(BasicAuth),
                    'Context': 'Context' + btoa(ContextHeader)
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"Id": "' + Id + '" }',
                url: URL + "/MethodName",
                success: function (result) {
                    response = result;
                    if (response == true)
                        Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true);
                    $('#msgDiv').fadeOut('slow');
                },
                error: function (status) {
                    console.log(status.status);
                    $('#msgDiv').fadeOut('slow');
                    Configurations.OnFailure(status);
                }
            });
```

Above code  i have written on javascript.

On HTTP call it working fine.But on HTTPS call its not working.

I am getting error like below on console

```
enter code here
```

- OPTIONS https://abc/xyz 400 (Bad Request)
- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://abc/xyz from origin 'https://Localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Comment: There's nothing in "Below Code", and you should put it **in the question** - but it seems like you haven't configured IIS to handle OPTIONS requests

Comment: I have checked on iis to handle options requests

Comment: I can see OPTIONS verb allowed in Request Filtering.

Comment: Yes, but the code you haven't shown (the server side code) clearly isn't actually handling OPTIONS request (just because IIS allows it, doesn't make it *handled*)

Comment: Are you able to get the right response by using PostMan Tool over Https? Besides, I add the below code to the Application_beginrequest event of global.asax file.  if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.End();
            }

Comment: Besides, one thing must be noted that we should install the server certificate in the local CA since the server use transport security.

Comment: I could not check using postman because its customer environment and  i have tried with adding above code on global.asax but it didn't work

Comment: I could not get your point. why can't you check it?  before we call the service by using JS, we should guarantee that our service have been correctly published over https.

Comment: @AbrahamQian - using POSTMAN won't check OPTIONS request anyway, so if OPTIONS request is not handled by the OP's code, then POSTMAN won't prove anything

Answer (score 0):

Here is My CORS solution, wish it is useful to you. Add the global application class to my wcf service application.
**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With,Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

**The web.config on server**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="https" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then install the server service certificate in the client (where we run the JS).
[image]
**JS.**

```
<script>
        function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;
            var hash = window.btoa(tok); //javascript built-in function
            return "Basic " + hash;
        }
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://vabqia130vm:12001/service1.svc/getdata?value=34",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth("administrator",
                        "abcde12345!"));
                },
                success: function (d) {
                    console.log(d);
                },

            });

        })
    </script>
```

**Result.**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score -2):

I have created dispatchmessageInspector on service side to check whether authentication is correct or not   before calling actual service.

Below code i have wrote for handling authentication on dispatcher inspector.

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            var logFileName = SetLogInfo("JavaScriptBasicAuth");
            try
            {
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("OPTIONS"))
                {
                    var basicAuth = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                    if (basicAuth != null)
                    {
                        string[] separator = basicAuth.Split(' ');
                        BasicAuthenticationBehaviorAttribute basicauth = new BasicAuthenticationBehaviorAttribute();
                        if (!basicauth.ValidateBasicAuth(separator[1]))
                        {
                            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileLogger.LogError("401 (Unauthorized) Error - " + "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Please contact administrator.", LOG_SUB_DIRECTORY, logFileName);
                        throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    }
            }
        }
```

**But Call is failing before Dispatcher inspector code.**

Comment: Why are you writing a non-answer as an answer to your own question?